# Default route not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Why doesn't this work?

Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Summary",
                "{controller}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Summary", action = "Default" }
            );
```

Controller:

```
public class SummaryController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Default(int id)
        {
            Summary summary = GetSummaryById(id);

            return View("Summary", summary);
        }
    }
```

URL:

```
http://localhost:40353/Summary/107
```

Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

    The resource cannot be found.

    Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

    Requested URL: /Summary/107

    Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225
```

**Update:**

Let me update the question with a more intelligent one. How can I have both of these?

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    "Home",
                    "{controller}",
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Default" }
                );

routes.MapRoute(
                    "Summary",
                    "{controller}/{id}",
                    new { controller = "Summary", action = "Default" }
                );
```

Comment: Try changing the parameter type of `id` from `int` to `string` in the `Default` action method.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. Same error message.

Comment: do you have any other route configuration ?

Comment: I copy pasted your controller class and routing and it worked for me.

Comment: It worked for me as well. I guess some other routing configuratin is breaking this

Comment: Okay. Now we're getting somewhere. I do have other pages with this same pattern. If I'm typing in the controller name as part of the URL, why would the system be confused? If I comment out the other routes, then it does, in fact, work, as some of you verified. How do I get this pattern to work for multiple pages/controllers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### How do routes work (by default)?

Let's get back to the default route, which is somewhat like this one:

```
routes.MapRoute(

    // Route name
    "Default", 

    // URL with parameters
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 

    // Parameter defaults
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 

);
```

Let's try to understand how this one works.

- If you access `/`, it will call the `Index` action of the `Home` controller; the optional Id was ommitted.
- If you access `/C` it will call the `Index` action of the `C` controller; the optional Id was ommitted.
- If you access `/C/A` it will call the `A` action of the `C` controller; the optional Id was ommitted.
- If you access `/C/A/1` it will call the `A` action of the `C` controller with id `1`.

So, that route allows any URLs of the form `/`, `/C`, `/C/A` and `/C/A/1` where `C` is a controller and `A` is an action. What does this mean? This means that you don't *necessarily* have to specify your own routes.

So, without routes you could just have a `HomeController` and a `SummaryController` and add an action to that last controller called `Show`.

Then `/Summary/Show/1` would call `SummaryController.Show(1)`

---

### What if I want to have a shorter route (/Controller/Id) for a controller?

Let's suppose we do want to map routes such that `/Summary/1` calls `SummaryController.Show(1)`.

Here is the correct form:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Summary",
    "Summary/{id}",
    new { controller = "Summary", action = "Show" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Note that we have changed the `Home` route to look like the `Default` route. Now we've added a `Summary` route where we tell that URLs of the form `Summary/{id}` will trigger that route. When they do, it calls the `Show` action of the `Summary` controller and pass along `id` as a parameter; which is exactly what you want...

Also note that we need to place the `Summary` route first such that it gets precedence.

***Caution:** You will not want to create a new route for every single action you create. You also don't want all your actions to be in the same controller. Consider rethinking your approach if one of these is the case, so that you don't end up with problems later...*

Comment: Tom, Thank you for the lengthy, detailed, and perspicuous response. I was able to get my code working based on your explanation. And, after a moment of pondering, I understood why you said I should place the Summary route before the default route (a key point for you to have made). I will add other routes that are of a format similar to Summary, all before the default route. I omitted the id for the default route, as I don't really need it. Also, and int works fine for the parameter to the Summary action. .NET parses it just fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing :

```
new { controller = "Summary", action = "Default" }
```

with :

```
new { controller = "Summary", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

**Edit:** tried your code, worked for me. Do you have any other routes defined in your global.asax?