# I want to put dash in URL in .net MVC.How to do it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, url

I am working with MVC5 where I am unable to put dashes in the URL. What I want is to put a dash between the words.Kindly view my working code.

My Route Config is:

```
            routes.Add(
                  new Route("{MyApple}/{page}",
                       new RouteValueDictionary(
                            new { controller = "MyApple", action = "Index", page = "" }),
                            new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
                  );
```

And My controller is :

```
public ActionResult Index(string page)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("/Views/MyApple/" + page + ".cshtml")))
    {
        string userId = "";
        if (Session["AppId"] != null)
        userId = Session["AppId"].ToString();

         Session["ReturnUrl"] = Url.Action("EmptyTemplate");
         IBaseViewModel model = new BaseViewModel();
         return View(page, model);
     }            
}
```

This is my controller where the parameters go to page.
Example: devpage = aspdotnet then it will render the view  = aspdotnet.html

Please help with this edited content.
I want to dash to the URL with lowercases. 
Example: Suppose I have perfectsolution.html page then i

`localhost/case-study/perfect-solution`

(Don't mind my English).Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Note: in the index page, I` am using  "perfect solution" to pass to the view but I want in URL, perfect-solution.

Comment: Hi, are you targeting a specific action in a single controller? Or is this a system wide adjustment? Can you show the relevant parts of your controller as well?

Comment: It is in the single controller. Ok, Lemme edit my question

Comment: Can you post the controller? I want to see the action's signatures.

Comment: I have posted my controller,,, have a  look

Comment: `in the index page, I am using "perfect solution" to pass to the view but I want in URL, perfect-solution`, just create a separate property for the Url. Then the dash won't bite you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want this type URL /case-studies/san-Diego-veg-festival ,
>   casestudies is controller and san-diego-veg-festival is parameter.

As per your comments , I made a guess that you are trying to pass parameter value in `CaseStudies` controller's `Index` method.

Two types of Routing to choose from, you can choose anyone as required:

**1. Convention-based Routing**

In Your `RouteConfig.cs` file make these changes:

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "CaseStudiesRoute",
           url: "case-studies/{devPage}",
           defaults: new { controller = "CaseStudies", action = "Index", devPage = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public class CaseStudiesController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index(string devPage)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Now using your browser give a `GET` request to URL , `/case-studies/san-Diego-veg-festival` , It should work with Convention-based Routing.

**2. Attribute Routing**

In Your `RouteConfig.cs` enable Attribute Routing , by adding `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` , Now `RouteConfig.cs` looks like:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public class CaseStudiesController : Controller
{

    [Route("case-studies/{devPage?}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string devPage)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Now using your browser give a `GET` request to URL , `/case-studies/san-Diego-veg-festival` , It should work with attribute routing.

**References**

[1.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

[2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435883/default-route-not-working)

Comment: Sorry, both are not working in my case . should I show you, my controller??

Comment: Yes please edit your post and add your controller and `RouteConfig.cs` details, it may help others to guide you better.

Comment: I have posted my controller.kindly have a look

Comment: @SiddharthRajput Why you are using custom route handler ? Did you try my answer , its easy way ? Also if you want url as `localhost/case-study/perfect-solution`
Just add Url Pattern as : 
`url: "case-study/{page}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Routing Attribute functionality

[Route("study/perfect-solution")]

eg:

```
[Route("study/perfect-solution")]
public ActionResult PerfectSolution()
{
// code here
}
```

If you want to pass parameters it need to be specified

Eg:

```
[Route("study/perfect-solution/{parameter}")]
public ActionResult PerfectSolution(string parameter)
{
// code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for it, but Yea, I have used it but. I want this type URL. /case-studies/san-Diego-veg-festival.How can I get it? NOTE: casestudies is controller and san-diego-veg-festival is parameter

Comment: is san-diego-veg-festival name of the action, or is this the argument you want to pass to the action?

Comment: it is a parameter that I am sending to URL

Comment: @SiddharthRajput , did you find the solution, if please mark this as answer?

Comment: then you can try it like this

`[Route("case-studies/{parameter}")]
public ActionResult PerfectSolution(string parameter)
{
// code here
}`
if you try calling like this /case-studies/san-Diego-veg-festival 
"san-Diego-veg-festival" will taken as value for parameter