# How to remove extra spaces between two words in a string?

Tags: c#, .net

```
ViewBag.Title = "Hello (123) world"
```

what I want is:

> "Hello 123 world"

Here is my code:

```
string input = ViewBag.Title;
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex re = new 
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[;\\\\/:*?\"<>|&'()-]");
ViewBag.MetaTitle = re.Replace(input, " "); //" " only one space here
```

Using this, I am getting:

```
Hello  123  world
```

There is extra one space between "hello" and "123" and "world" due to brackets. How can I remove those extra spaces?

Comment: Pro tips: (1) if you want to show spaces in strings, use inline or block formatting. (2) there's no need to add please-help-me and kindly-help-me waffle, especially in titles - native English speakers will sometimes interpret this as a form of begging. Titles are best focussing on the detail of what you are aiming for anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, split and rebuilt your string:

```
string input = "Hello world (707)(y)(9) ";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex re = new
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[;\\\\/:*?\"<>|&'()-]");
//split
var x = re.Split(input);
//rebuild
var newString = string.Join(" ", x.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c))
                                  .Select(c => c.Trim()));
```

newString equals:

> Hello world 707 y 9

Comment: @SiddharthRajput: note the note that has been added ;-)

Comment: Stefen, i have one more question regarding routing..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936141/i-want-to-put-dash-in-url-in-net-mvc-how-to-do-it Here. Kindly help me .:)

Answer (score 2):

from the comments in @SCoutos answer the OP wants replace certain chars with spaces but **only if the there is no spacing around the char**

modify the regex to:

```
"\\s?[;\\\\/:*?\"<>|&'()-]+\\s?"
```

so for 
`Hello World (707(y)(9)` you get

> Hello World 707 y 9

Example code:

```
const string TARGET_STRING = "Hello World (707(y)(9)";
var regEx = new Regex("\\s?[;\\\\/:*?\"<>|&'()-]+\\s?");
string result = regEx.Replace(TARGET_STRING, " ");
```

see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KpFY6X

Comment: @SiddharthRajput you still have to replace all matches with a space like you do in your example...

Comment: yea, my code is working now exactly what I wanted with Stefen code.Thanks

Comment: @SiddharthRajput did not escape the `\s` - changed the regex to a string that you can copy and paste into your code...

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the unwanted characters by a blank string will do the trick:

```
ViewBag.MetaTitle = re.Replace(input, "");
```

Comment: Not as a general matter, but in the op's case, the extra spaces are generated by a wrong replace function.

Comment: Sure, Please provide me solution if possible

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: Logic should be like if there is already space, the function should remove it and if there is a special character, it will be removed and add space.

Comment: @SiddharthRajput: you want to split the numbers as well?

Comment: then kindly remove it if possible

Comment: Thank you @SCouto